# Laravel BelongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma tabela de usuários que faz relacionamento com perfil `belongsTo`, e o perfil faz relacionamento com itens da área `belongsToMany` , e itens da área faz relacionamento com área `belongsTo`, ele está trazendo o meu item da área, mas eu gostaria de trazer tbm a minha área nos dados, alguém saberia me informar como posso fazer isso ?

Estou fazendo a chamada da seguinte forma

```
Auth::user()->profiles->areasItens->toArray();
```

Comment: só continuar chamando o relacionamento, ->area->areaItens->toArray já que área contém itens, então área um para n

Answer (score 2):

Utilize seu model User por exemplo:

```
$user = User::with(['profiles.areasItens'])
         ->findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

print_r($user->toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o with resolva seu problema:

```
Auth::user()->with("profiles", 
     "profiles.areaItens", 
     "profiles.areaItens.area")
     ->profiles->areaItens->toArray();
```